# How to make a python program that lists the position/positions of a certain word in a sentence

Tags: python, position, analysis, identify

I'm trying to figure out how to make a python program that highlights the position/positions of a certain inputed word in a sentence and lists what place that word is. For example if the sentence was: "The fat cat sat on the mat"
then the position for the word fat would be Number 2.

Heres what Ive got so far:

```
varSentence = ("The fat cat sat on the mat")

print (varSentence)

varWord = input("Enter word ")

varSplit = varSentence.split()

if varWord in varSplit:
    print ("Found word")
else:
    print ("Word not found")
```

Comment: Which part of the task do you have problems with?

Comment: I have got the program to analyse if a word is in the sentence, just having trouble trying to make it list what position that word is in.

Comment: We are expecting from you that you started working on the problem and you are blocked, that's why you request us our help. So our question is: where are you blocked? If your answer is "at the beginning", then you're clearly at the wrong place on SO. Did you write some algo on a piece of paper?

Comment: I will add the program so far @Cilyan

Comment: You should probably first split the sentence into words, i.e. convert one big string into a list of little strings, each containing one word. Then you go from word to word and see which one is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to convert your sentence int a list of words, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate positions, and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)   to generate your results list.

```
>>> sentence = "The fat cat sat on the mat"
>>> words = sentence.lower().split()
>>> word_to_find = "the"
>>> [pos for pos, word in enumerate(words, start=1) if word == word_to_find]
[1, 6]
```

If the word is not found your result will be an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. I created it for a task at school, though it should help if you break it down

```
UserSen = input("Please type in a sentence without punctuation:")
print("User has input:",UserSen)
WordFindRaw = input("Please enter a word you want to search for in the sentence:")
print("The word requested to be seacrhed for is:",WordFindRaw)
UserSenLow = UserSen.lower()
WordFind = WordFindRaw.lower()
SenLst = []
SenLst.append(UserSenLow)
print(SenLst)
if any(WordFind in s for s in SenLst):
print("Search successful. The word '",WordFind,"' has been found in position(s):")
else:
print("Search unsuccessful. The word '",WordFind,"' was not found. Please try another word...")
```